# Possible to make parent honour width of child image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a parent element honour the width of a child image.

It works on load, but if you resize the height of the viewport to force a change in the image height, the parent element 'remembers' the initial size of the image and maintains that width.

If you mimic the above with width instead of height, there is no problem.

Here is a video of the behaviour: http://jmp.sh/8VEOZS8

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/YWgvdw

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x960" />
</div>
```

I'm interested to know:

1) why this is happening

2) if there is a way to fix it

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it by setting `max-width` and `max-height` attributes to the image so it wont overflow the wrapper or the window. Then you can set the `display: inline-block;` to the wrapper instead which is nowadays used in replacement of floating elements. I set the image to be `display: block;` just so it will display it as a block element and eliminate weird space around it etc.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x960" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately this doesn't have the desire effect, finding that it does not honour the viewport height: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/NAJLrP

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve?

Comment: It is part of a bigger interface but I have tried to distill it down to the essence of this particular problem. Essentially, there is another wrapping element that is dictating the height of the wrapper and the image. The behaviour I want is what occurs on load, but for it to be fluid with resize too - I've updated the pen: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/YWgvdw

Comment: I have a feeling it may be more easily fixed with JS, and perhaps aligned with a resize event. But, still, I am curious as to why it behaves this way - seems like a quirk of CSS.